# Why is my EditText style not being applied?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-view, android-xml, android-styles

I try like this:

`styles.xml`:

```
<style name="EditTextStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">12dp</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/editTextUnderline</item>
        <item name="android:drawableLeft">@drawable/ic_sample_action</item>
        <item name="android:drawablePadding">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">15dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">25dp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorTextPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/editTextHintColor</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/viga</item>
        <item name="android:inputType">text</item>
    </style>
```

And then I use it in layout file:

```
 <EditText
            style="@style/EditTextStyle"
            android:id="@+id/input_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="Title"
            android:text="@={viewModel.title}" />
```

However I do not see any changes. Why could that be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chanded style parent to `@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText` and it worked.